# How to Pass Jsonstringfy object with other parameters

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

****I want pass more parameter with json stringify()  but when passing other variable getting null value. please let me know right way of passing more variable .****

I have tried this

```js
data: {model:JSON.stringify(arr), buildingid ,shopid,post},
```

```js
$("#btnArchive").click(function () {
    var Buildingid = $("#BuildingId").val();
    var shopid = $("#ShopId").val();
    var Post = $("#SelectedValue").val();

    var arr = [];
    debugger;
    //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
    var customers = new Array();
    $(".tblSavingCollChk:checked").each(function () {
        var row = $(this).attr("chkid");
        alert(row);
        debugger;
        //customers.push(row);
        arr.push({ Id: row });
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Archive/UpdateStatus",
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            if (r == true) {
                alert("Record Updated successfully");
                document.location = '@Url.Action("ArchiveList","Archive")';
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {},
    });
});
```

Controller action
public ActionResult UpdateStatus([FromBody] ArchiveViewModel[] model,string buildingid, string shopid, string Post)//List values)
{}

Comment: What's your parameter of UpdateStatus  in your controller ?

Comment: public ActionResult UpdateStatus([FromBody] ArchiveViewModel[] model,string buildingid, string shopid, string Post)//List<string> values){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass more variable,I have a work demo like below, you can refer to it:

remove `[Frombody]` and dataType,contentType

In the controller:

```
public class jsonPostController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetData(AuthorVM jsonInput ,string cc, string buildingid, string shopid)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="submit" />

<input id="BuildingId" value="aa" type="hidden" />
<input id="ShopId" value="aaa" type="hidden" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
        $("#btnGet").click(function () 
{  
    // Initialization  
            var arr = new Array();
            var  ListOfAuthors = { Id: 23, Name: "John" };
            arr.push(ListOfAuthors);
            var jsonInput = {};
            jsonInput.Authors = arr;
            var buildingid = $("#BuildingId").val();
            var shopid = $("#ShopId").val();
    $.ajax(  
        {  
            type: 'POST',                 
            url: '/jsonPost/GetData',                   
            data: {
                        jsonInput: jsonInput,
                        cc: "cc", buildingid: buildingid, shopid: shopid
                    },       
        });          
});
    });

</script>
```

Author:

```
public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }      
    }
```

**Update**

If you want to pass array, we can add a new model , ajax change as above:

AuthorVm:

```
public class AuthorVm
    {
        public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }   
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot  its working for other variable but  Still i am getting null because have to use array object to pass bulk of data that's why  added checked values in array. please let me know how to pass array also

Comment: please suggest me how to pass array and other variable.

Comment: @Jayaacharya To pass array , I make some change at ajax and add a new model, please see my update.